Insert images/sticker/gif in Edittext in android from custom keyboard/google keyboard in .NET MAUI Hybrid Razor Application
I'm working on a .NET MAUI hybrid Razor application and facing an issue with GIF and sticker insertion using the Android default keyboard. Specifically, when users try to insert GIFs or stickers, they are not displayed correctly in the application.
Has anyone encountered this issue before, and could you provide guidance or steps to resolve this? I would appreciate a detailed implementation to handle GIF and sticker support in a .NET MAUI app.
Here are the key details of the issue:
.NET MAUI Hybrid (Razor) application
GIFs and stickers from the Android keyboard are not inserted as expected
Looking for a step-by-step implementation to handle this properly.
Any help or insight would be highly appreciated!
using Microsoft.Maui.Handlers;
using Android.Views.InputMethods;
using Android.OS;
using AndroidX.Core.View.InputMethod;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.Provider;
using Uri = Android.Net.Uri;

namespace Sample.Messenger.Client.Platforms.Android
{
#if ANDROID
    public class MyCustomEntry : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Editor
    {
        public delegate void ImageCommittedEventHandler(Uri contentUri, string mimeType);
        public event ImageCommittedEventHandler OnImageCommitted;

        public MyCustomEntry()
        {
            // Custom initialization if needed
        }
#endif

        internal void RaiseImageCommitted(Uri contentUri, string mimeType)
        {
            OnImageCommitted?.Invoke(contentUri, mimeType);
        }
    }

    public class MyCustomEntryHandler : EditorHandler
    {
        protected override AppCompatEditText CreatePlatformView()
        {
            var customEditText = new MyCustomEditText(Context, VirtualView as MyCustomEntry);
            customEditText.InputType = InputTypes.TextFlagMultiLine;
            customEditText.SetHorizontallyScrolling(false);
            return customEditText;
        }
    }

    public class MyCustomEditText : AppCompatEditText
    {
        private readonly MyCustomEntry _virtualView;

        public MyCustomEditText(Context context, MyCustomEntry virtualView) : base(context)
        {
            _virtualView = virtualView;
        }

        public override IInputConnection OnCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs)
        {
            var ic = base.OnCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);
            if (ic == null) return null;

            EditorInfoCompat.SetContentMimeTypes(outAttrs, new[] {
                "image/gif",
                "image/png",
                "image/jpeg",
                "image/webp"
            });

            return InputConnectionCompat.CreateWrapper(ic, outAttrs, new CommitContentListener(_virtualView));
        }

        private class CommitContentListener : Java.Lang.Object, InputConnectionCompat.IOnCommitContentListener
        {
            private readonly MyCustomEntry _virtualView;

            public CommitContentListener(MyCustomEntry virtualView)
            {
                _virtualView = virtualView;
            }

            public bool OnCommitContent(InputContentInfoCompat inputContentInfo, int flags, Bundle opts)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Request permission if needed
                    if ((flags & InputConnectionCompat.InputContentGrantReadUriPermission) != 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            inputContentInfo.RequestPermission();
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    var contentUri = inputContentInfo.ContentUri;
                    var mimeType = inputContentInfo.Description.GetMimeType(0);

                    Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        _virtualView?.RaiseImageCommitted(contentUri, mimeType);
                    });

                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                finally
                {
                    inputContentInfo?.ReleasePermission();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    using var stream = a.GetManifestResourceStream("Sample.Messenger.Client.appsettings.json");

    if (stream == null) { throw new Exception("appsetting.json is missing"); }

    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .AddJsonStream(stream)
          .Build();

    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .UseMauiCompatibility()
        .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
        });
#if ANDROID
    builder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
    {
        handlers.AddHandler<MyCustomEntry, MyCustomEntryHandler>();
    });
#endif
}


See this official doc: Entry input method editor options on Android.
